# The type new View.OnClickListener must implement the inherited abstract method

Tags: java, android, eclipse, inheritance

So I just started programming, but I dont really get the method OnClickListener. I already google the error I have: "The type new View.OnClickListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method View.OnClickListener.OnClick(View)" and I tried to change some things in my code, but it still doens't work. Can anyone tell me exactly what I need to change in my code? Thanks in advance.

MainMenuScreen.java:

```
package com.wouter.testjk;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainMenuScreen extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);
 //error on the line below
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.one_player)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { //the error is here
            public void onClick(View V) {
                Log.d("DEBUG", "One Player Button Pressed!");
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenuScreen.this, TicTacToeGame.class);
                intent.putExtra("gameType", true);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.two_player)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View V) {
                Log.d("DEBUG", "Two Player Button Pressed!");
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenuScreen.this, TicTacToeGame.class);
                intent.putExtra("gameType", false);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.exit_game)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View V) {
                Log.d("DEBUG", "Exit Game Button Pressed!");
                MainMenuScreen.this.finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.wouter.testjk;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.wouter.testjk.R;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private TicTacToeGame mGame;

    private Button mBoardButtons[];

    private TextView mInfoTextView;
    private TextView mPlayeroneCount;
    private TextView mTieCount;
    private TextView mPlayertwoCount;
    private TextView mPlayeroneText; 
    private TextView mPlayertwoText;

    private int mPlayeroneCounter = 0;
    private int mTieCounter = 0;
    private int mPlayertwoCounter = 0;

    private boolean mPlayeroneFirst = true;
    private boolean mIsSinglePlayer = false;
    private boolean mIsPlayerOneTurn = true;
    private boolean mGameOver = false;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        boolean mGameType = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("gametype");

        mBoardButtons = new Button[mGame.getBOARD_SIZE()];
        mBoardButtons[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.one);
        mBoardButtons[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.two);
        mBoardButtons[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.three);
        mBoardButtons[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.four);
        mBoardButtons[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.five);
        mBoardButtons[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.six);
        mBoardButtons[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seven);
        mBoardButtons[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eight);
        mBoardButtons[8] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nine);

        Button mTen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ten);
        mTen.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button mEleven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eleven);
        mEleven.setOnClickListener(this);



        mInfoTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.information);
        mPlayeroneCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.humancount);
        mTieCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tiesCount);
        mPlayertwoCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.androidCount);
        mPlayeroneText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.human);
        mPlayertwoText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.android);

        mPlayeroneCount.setText(Integer.toString(mPlayeroneCounter));
        mTieCount.setText(Integer.toString(mTieCounter));
        mPlayeroneCount.setText(Integer.toString(mPlayertwoCounter));

        mGame = new TicTacToeGame();

        startNewGame(mGameType);

    }

    private void startNewGame(boolean isSingle)
    {
        //some code here
    }

    private class ButtonClickListener implements View.OnClickListener
    {
        int location;

        public ButtonClickListener(int location)
        {
            this.location = location;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (!mGameOver)
            {
                if(mBoardButtons[location].isEnabled())
                {
                    if(mIsSinglePlayer)
                    {
                         setMove(mGame.PLAYER_ONE, location);

                         int winner = mGame.checkForWinner();

                         if (winner == 0)
                         {
                             mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_computer);
                             int move = mGame.getComputerMove();
                             setMove(mGame.PLAYER_TWO, move);
                             winner = mGame.checkForWinner();

                         }
                         if (winner == 0)
                                 mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_human);
                         else if (winner == 1)
                         {
                             mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_tie);
                             mTieCounter++;
                             mTieCount.setText(Integer.toString(mTieCounter));
                             mGameOver = true;
                         }       
                         else if (winner ==2)
                         {
                             mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_human_wins);
                             mPlayeroneCounter++;
                             mPlayeroneCount.setText(Integer.toString(mPlayeroneCounter));
                             mGameOver = true;
                         }
                         else if (winner ==3)
                         {
                             mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_android_wins);
                             mPlayertwoCounter++;
                             mPlayertwoCount.setText(Integer.toString(mPlayertwoCounter));
                             mGameOver = true;
                         }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(mIsPlayerOneTurn)
                        {
                            setMove(mGame.PLAYER_ONE, location);
                        }
                        else
                        {setMove(mGame.PLAYER_TWO, location);

                        }


                        int winner = mGame.checkForWinner();

                        if (winner == 0)
                        {
                            if(mIsPlayerOneTurn)
                            {
                                mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_player_two);
                                mIsPlayerOneTurn = false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.turn_player_one);
                                mIsPlayerOneTurn = true;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (winner == 1)
                        {
                            mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.result_tie);
                            mTieCounter++;
                            mTieCount.setText(Integer.toString(mTieCounter));
                            mGameOver = true;
                        }       
                        else if (winner ==2)
                        {
                            mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.player_one_wins);
                            mPlayeroneCounter++;
                            mPlayeroneCount.setText(Integer.toString(mPlayeroneCounter));
                            mGameOver = true;
                        }
                        else if (winner ==3)
                        {
                            mInfoTextView.setText(R.string.player_two_wins);
                            mPlayertwoCounter++;
                            mPlayertwoCount.setText(Integer.toString(mPlayertwoCounter));
                            mGameOver = true;
                     }
                    }
                }
            }    
        }
    }

    private void setMove(char player, int location)
    {
        mGame.setMove(player,location);
        mBoardButtons[location].setEnabled(false);
        mBoardButtons[location].setText(String.valueOf(player));
        if (player == mGame.PLAYER_ONE)
            mBoardButtons[location].setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        else
        {
            mBoardButtons[location].setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId())
        {
        case R.id.ten:

            startNewGame(mIsSinglePlayer);
            return;

        case R.id.eleven:

            MainActivity.this.finish();
            return;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line the error is thrown at?

Comment: Of course, I forgot to indicateit. I updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a project error. First follow good code guidelines.

1. When overriding a method (e.g. onClick) add an `@Override` annotation before it. This will make the compiler yell, if such method doesn't exist.
2. Specify which class your interface belongs to by using `View.OnClickListener`.
3. `Button` already is a `View`, no need to cast it just to set a OnClickListener.

Here's what it might look like:

```
// No need to cast it to a button here, as it 
findViewById(R.id.one_player).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "One Player Button Pressed!");
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenuScreen.this, TicTacToeGame.class);
        intent.putExtra("gameType", true);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
});
```

Lastly *clean/rebuild* your project as this error doesn't occur to me when using your code.

Comment: Okay I tried this, and clean/rebuild. But the error still occurs

Comment: Now it works, I copied the sentence with findViewById(R.id.two_player)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { and pasted it, and changed two to one, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

`OnClickListener` is an **interface** that defines the method `void onClick(View v)`. Adding the `implements OnClickListener` to you Activity class means that that class implements the interface and thus must have that `onClick(View view)` method. This is mainly done so that you can pass `this` on places an `OnClickListener` is needed and which you also did.

But, as you coded it, you should remove the `implements OnClickListener`part from your Activity and instead pass instances of your ButtonClickListener class as OnClickListeners to your buttons like so:

```
Button mTen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ten);
mTen.setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickListener(10)); /* 10 is just a guess */
Button mEleven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eleven);
mEleven.setOnClickListener(new ButtonClickListener(11)); /* 11 is just a guess */
```